# Continuity of $[x]+\sqrt{x-[x]}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Please how to study the continuity on R of the function $$f(x)=[x]+\sqrt{x-[x]}$$

I say if x is in $\mathbb{Z}$ then f(x)=x, so f is continuous on $\mathbb{Z}$ .

What about $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\complement_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by $[x]$. It can represent the floor function or the round function. The answer is different in each case.

Comment: "Continuous on $\mathbb{Z}$" is impossible since there is a gap between all integers, which is a discontinuity. Presumably you meant that $f$ (on $\mathbb{R}$) is continuous at the integers but you can't show that from $f(n)=n$ alone. Notice that the same thing is true for $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: [.] is the floor function

Comment: Why do you think $f(x) = x$ on a set means it is continuous on the set? That needn't be true if a point on the set doesn't have a neighborhood entirely in the set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume $[x]=\lfloor x\rfloor$, is the floor function.

---

For $x\in(k,k+1)$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, you have $f(x)=k+\sqrt{x-k}$, which is a continuous function.
So the problem with continuity may occur in integer points only.

Check at $x=k$, where $k$ is an integer.

$f(k)=k$.

$\lim_{x\to k^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to k^+}(k+\sqrt{x-k})=k$ as in this case we can look at $x\in(k,k+1)$ only.

$\lim_{x\to k^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to k^-}(k-1+\sqrt{x-(k-1)})=k-1+1=k$ as in this case we can look at $x\in(k-1,k)$ only.

Hence $f$ is continuous at $x=k$. Summarizing, $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.

See the graph: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Floor%5Bx%5D%2BSqrt%5Bx-Floor%5Bx%5D%5D

Comment: we must do the limit at right and at left at each integer k or just 0 ? @tong_nor

Comment: At any point $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ you have $f(k)=k$ and both limits are equal $k$ (you check this by exactly the same argument as I did for $k=0$).

Comment: The derivability is studied in the same way ?

Comment: @lindaOiladali: your function is not differentiable at the integers.

Comment: @lindaOiladali: now, as an excercise, try to prove yourself, that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ iff $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I calculate the derivative at left and right k a find it $\infty$ the same at k+1, so f is differentiable on $\cup ]k,k+1[$ @trong_nor right ?

Comment: please @tong_nor , I prove easily that $f([n,n+1[)=[n,n+1[$ how to deduce the monotony of f ? please

Comment: in two cases: 1) $x_1,x_2\in[k,k+1)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$; 2) $x_1,x_2$ lie in two distinct intervals

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$: $[x+k]=k+[x]$

We have $f(x+k)=[x+k]+\sqrt{x+k-[x+k]}=k+[x]-\sqrt{x-[x]}=k+f(x)$

You can check continuity on $(0,1]$ now.